How to prove that Binary 1 is a cyclic group and Binary 2 is a dihedral group?
enter image description here
What steps and properties should I examine in each case to determine this? Any help with the process or detailed explanation would be appreciated!
Attached image for reference.

One single $G$ cannot:  you will end up with several different possible tables.  One of them will be $D_2$, and the others will be $C_4$ in disguise.  Use the Latin square properties to work this out.

Here is how you can use Cayley table to verify that set G can represent both a cyclic group $C_4$ and a dihedral group $D_2$ which has order 4( 2 reflections and 2 rotations):
I have a set G ={e,a,b,c}. Also I can write down G={e,a,$a^2$,$a^3$} where I am interpreting b and c in terms of power of a. This process assumes G is a Cyclic group $C_4$, where all elements are generated by repeated application of a single generator a.
Now let's construct Cayley table for $C_4$ and verify that $C_4$ is indeed a cyclic group of order 4.
The Cayley table for $C_4$ is:



$*$
$e$
$a$
$a^2$
$a^3$




$e$
$e$
$a$
$a^2$
$a^3$


$a$
$a$
$a^2$
$a^3$
$e$


$a^2$
$a^2$
$a^3$
$e$
$a$


$a^3$
$a^3$
$e$
$a$
$a^2$



Note: (a^n)=e where n is a multiple of 4 because since the group cycles back to identity element after (a^3).
From this Cayley table you can verify the group properties:

There exists a generator which is (a) such that all the elements can be generated as its powers.
The group operation is associative( (ab)c=a(bc)).
The group is closed under operation.
There is an identity e such that ae=ea for all a.
There exists an inverse. For an element (a^k), there is a inverse $(a^k)^{-1}$ of $a^m$ such that $a^k \cdot a^m = e$.

Now let's construct Cayley table for dihedral group $D_2$:



*
e
r
s
rs




e
e
r
s
rs


r
r
e
rs
s


s
s
rs
e
r


rs
rs
s
r
e



Here G={e,a,b,c} can be represented as $D_2$={e,r,s,rs}. As $D_2$ is the isomorphic to G. From this Cayley table you can verify the group properties like above.
Note: If you show that both dihedral group $D_2$ and Cyclic group $C_4$ are isomorphic to G , it will strengthen the verification that G can represent a Cyclic group and dihedral group of order 4.

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
